# Selenium C# - How to tell Selenium, that we have been redirected to another page? (ADFS authentication)

Tags: c#, selenium, redirect

I've recently started using the Selenium WebDriver. Very soon after that I was blocked by the following problem.

I want to test a platform which firstly requires the user to sign in with Microsoft account, then the user gets redirected to a company's ADFS page. After the user enters his credentials, he is finally landed on the desired page.

Basically, I succeed to login the user with the MS credentials and I get redirected to the ADFS page. The problem is that when I am redirected, Selenium doesn't recognize that I am on a different page, so further test is not possible...I saw a solution with frames, but that is not applicable in this case, since there are no frames here...

Code until now:

```
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {

            //Go to desired page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.test/");
           //User gets redirected to MS login platform
        }

        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTest()
        {
            //Writing email and clicking on next in order to re-direct to ADSF
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("element1"));
            element.SendKeys("test@test.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("button")).Click();

            //Trying to write credentials in the ADSF page                
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("element2"));
            element.SendKeys("test@test.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("element3"));
            element.SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Button2")).Click();

        }
```

Result StackTrace:

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)

   Result Message:  
   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"passwordInput"}
```

**UPDATE:**  After trying everything from the mentioned below and checking some articles regarding the ADSF authorization, I assume that the problem is not due to no waiting of the page to load/wrong ID,Names etc, or something similar.. I assume that the ADSF page itself is protected against automation and another solution has to be found out.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace that you are getting when trying to enter credentials in the ADFS page.

Comment: I added the "Result StackTrace"

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is being raised. So, either `.SendKeys` is executing before the element is visible. In that case you will have to use explicit wait (as shown by @Nikolay Barakov). Or the `.Name` is dynamic (which by the looks of it, seems to be so). In that case change the locator and try. I would suggest to use XPath here.

Comment: Selenium knows you are on another page but your script doesn't. You need to add code that detects what page the browser is on and what to do on that page.

Answer (score 0):

After login, try this -

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Selenium still doesn't find the Id (also tried with Name) of the desired field...

Comment: Try to getcurrenturl of the page after login - driver.getcurrenturl(); . i think it should print the first page url meaning driver is still getting the previous page. You can try refresh the page driver.navigate().refresh() or you can wait as stated in the other comment. let me know.

Comment: After trying the two methods, it still throws an error that the Id cannot be found..

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are gettin "element not found" or "element not visible" error. You can check that you are on the correct page, or can try to to wait the page to be fully loaded like this:

```
       public void WaitForPageToBeFullyLoaded(int timeSpan)
    {
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeSpan)).Until(
            d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    }
```

Other option is to wait for a element to be visible or clickable:

```
    public IWebElement WaitForCondition(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondition,
        double timeout)
    {
        var webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));

        return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondition);
    }
```

Comment: This is the closest to working at the moment...When I use one of the two suggestions, It doesn't throw errors when executing. The problem is that it still doesn't write anything in the credential fields on the ADSF page.. ;/ (in other words Не става и не става..;д)

Comment: Are you sure that the id is not dynamic and changes every time you access the page, try with className, cssSelector or with xpath